# Are there any JavaScript libraries exclusively for WebKit?

Tags: javascript, webkit

With mobile devices or embedded systems you often support only one browser for performance and memory reasons. With traditional JS libraries you must limit yourself in features and performance to support as many browsers as possible.
This is exactly what I would like to avoid.

Are their any JavaScript libraries out there focusing only on one web browser? Like jQuery, but without all the cross-browser stuff.

So far, the only library I've found is http://xuijs.com/

Comment: Which versions of WebKit?  Safari and Chrome use different JS engines.

Comment: jQuery and others libraries are already optimized for it, they test the browser features only once.

Comment: M28, you should make your comment into an answer. +1!

Comment: @M28 WebKit for Mobile is *not the same* as WebKit on the desktop, and jQuery and other frameworks are still pretty tentative about **real** mobile support (new events, etc)

Comment: Also I think focusing on just one platform is a terrible mistake, and most opinion from industry cogniscenti that I've seen agrees - look around for market statistics. Limiting your app to one platform is going to make your app someday look like the dreck we currently suffer from in the "IE6 Only!" wilderness.

Comment: @R. Bemrose, Yes, the JS engines probably come with somewhat different feature set. Do you know what V8 offer over Safari's engine?

Comment: @M28, Makes sense now that you mention it. That leaves a library taking advantage of specific browser features (CSS3, browser-specific APIs).

Comment: @Pointy, It can make sense. For example, embedded systems, information kiosks and similar.

Comment: @Carl I was talking specifically about the mobile market

Comment: Added my comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out ZeptoJS: http://github.com/madrobby/zepto

Answer (score 1):

[jQTouch](http://jqtouch.com) is jQuery-based, but very heavily WebKit-oriented.

Comment: True. But still comes with jQuery and all its cross-browser support/features :( But who knows, maybe the performance difference isn't that big.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery and others libraries are already optimized for it, they test the browser features only once.